# Python: Fastes way to iterate over Pandas DataFrame Column, but need to loop again inside the cell over an array

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I need to iterate over a Column over Numbers and loop inside the Cell Again because it's an array.
It works but it is slow i think, any idea to make it faster?

```
def CategoryBuilder(Deliverynote):
    CategoryBuilder = {}
    for l in Deliverynote:
        
        CategoryBuilder['{}'.format(l)] = df_cleared['Shopkategorie'].loc[df_cleared['Deliverynotenumber'] == l]

    return CategoryBuilder   


df_Kopf['Categories'] = df_Kopf.apply(lambda row: CategoryBuilder(row['Deliverynote']), axis = 1)
```

df_cleared['Lieferscheine'] is in code example df_cleared['Deliverynote']
FYI: Deliverynote = Lieferscheine

Input:
[image: Input]

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: pandas dataframes tend to be slow when dealing with large amounts of data. you can reset your table as dictionary of lists or list-of-lists -- the basic data types allow for more optimization.

Comment: @will.cass.wrig will try that

Comment: Can you give us example data? Inputs and outputs? You almost certainly should be using a `groupby` here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i added screenshot, tell me if you need more or an additional screenshot of the other dataframe